# how to serialize nested list into json format

Tags: c#, json

I have a List Object which internal contains a list of Products Object. I have to return this as a Json format to UI.

Here is the sample nested List which I am getting.
[How to add List<B> to Object A, where List<B> is part of class A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958355/how-to-add-listb-to-object-a-where-listb-is-part-of-class-a/60959654?noredirect=1#comment107850087_60959654)

I am using JsonResult to return a Json format, but only Customer list Object is getting converted. inner list Product object is missing.

Please someone suggest me how the nested list gets serialized.

Comment: Did you tried Newtonsoft?  string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);

Comment: Please, share your code and attempts to solve your problem

Comment: @AlleXyS: I tried Newtonsoft json, but its return type is string. my method in controller return type is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult.

Comment: you return an Ok(customers), right? Are you sure the problem is not from frontend? test json using a variable before returining Ok and check the string if contain Products property

Comment: If I'm right, your products property name is _products. I don't know in frontend its works. Please rename it to Products, and be sure that in your frontend you have same property name 'Products'. If you use a SPA, test if 'products' exist (start with lowercase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two list

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<Products> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//initialize Object of Customer here
```

Use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) to convert Customer object into json

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCustomer);
```

You can also take advantage of several formatting options available.

**Update**
Per your comment - pass the serialize data

```
return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCustomer))
```

Also, if you direct pass objCustomer like

```
return Ok(objCustomer)
```

it should return you Json (provided you have not configured your project to return another format by default)

Comment: mind that I added the JsonProperty, which gives you an added flexibility to format your json.

Comment: return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCustomer))

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want to return the customers list from your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958355/how-to-add-listb-to-object-a-where-listb-is-part-of-class-a/60959654?noredirect=1#comment107850087_60959654):

you need to import **Newtonsoft.Json** package into your application

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public your_method() {

   List<Customer> customers = your_method_to_return_curstomers();
   var jsonValue = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
}
```

[Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KcRjGq)

please init your Products list in Customer constructor (I don't now if this can be a possibility for your problem)

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer() {
      Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Products> Products {get;set;}      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AlleXys - "return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCustomer));" works for me shared by sandiejat.

Comment: Your controller must be capable to convert automatically the returning objects into json and inverse, IActionResults parameters (which are first time json/headers into objects)